# Thymeleaf - how to chose not null object in form

Tags: thymeleaf

Trying to check if object is not null in form:

```
<form th:action="@{register}" th:object="${loginInfo != null ? loginInfo.account : account}" method="post">
<input th:field="*{phoneNumber}"/>
```

If `loginInfo` defined and not null I want to use `loginInfo.account` in form.
Otherwise I want to use `account` object.

How to do that?

In example above I get `IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginInfo!= null ? loginInfo' available as request attribute`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Since we can't add a conditionals inside a `th:object`, then the only other way to achieve this, is using a `th:block` with a `th:if`. Of course, this will mean that you need your form's inputs in a template, otherwise you will have to duplicate code. I am assuming of course that loginInfo.account have the same fields as account.

First, let's create our template inside our layouts folder. For this example, this html file will be called `form-inputs`.

```
<th:block th:fragment="form-inputs">
    <input th:field="*{phoneNumber}"/>
</th:block>
```

Now, the page will have the following code to decide which object to use. If `loginInfo` is not null, then we will use it's account information, otherwise, we will use `account`.

```
<th:block th:if="${loginInfo!=null}">
    <form th:action="@{register}" th:object="${loginInfo.account}" method="post">
        <section th:replace="layouts/form-inputs :: form-inputs" th:remove="tag">
        </section>
    </form>
</th:block>
<th:block th:if="${loginInfo == null}">
    <form th:action="@{register}" th:object="${account}" method="post">
        <section th:replace="layouts/form-inputs :: form-inputs" th:remove="tag">
        </section>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

Hope this helps you!